# 2D array update in function in c

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to use the function `Initialize` to update the value of array `distance`, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NOT_CONNECTED -1

int nodesCount;

void Initialize(int (*distance)[nodesCount], int nodesCount) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i <= nodesCount; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j <= nodesCount; ++j) {
            distance[i][j] = NOT_CONNECTED;
        }
        distance[i][i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= nodesCount; i++)
        printf("distance[%d] = %d\n", i, distance[i][i]);

}

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &nodesCount);

    int distance[nodesCount + 1][nodesCount + 1];
    Initialize(distance, nodesCount);

    for(int i = 0; i <= nodesCount; i++)
        printf("distance[%d] = %d\n", i, distance[i][i]);
}
```

But the test result printed out shows the updated array value is wired, could anybody explain what might have happened to this code?

```
distance[0] = 0
distance[1] = 0
distance[2] = 0
distance[3] = 0
distance[4] = 0
distance[5] = 0
distance[0] = 0
distance[1] = -1
distance[2] = -1
distance[3] = -1
distance[4] = -1
distance[5] = 32677
```

Comment: `printf("distance[%d]=%d\n", i,distance[i][i]);` are keys in `distance` correctly used?

Comment: What's the `+1` for? You don't pass it to your function, so it assumes a wrong array geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
void Initialize(int (*distance)[nodesCount], int nodesCount)
```

compiler has no idea what is `nodesCount` in `int (*distance)[nodesCount]` because it has not seen it yet declared. This should be

```
void Initialize(int nodesCount, int (*distance)[nodesCount])
```

Then, you should pass `nodesCount+1` to `Initialize` function

```
Initialize(nodesCount+1, distance);
```

Note that in function `Initialize`you have to change every occurrence of  `<=nodesCount` in `for` loops to `<nodesCount`.

```
for (i=0; i<nodesCount; ++i){ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @FelixPalmen; Thanks. Corrected that.

Comment: I think the only problem was here `Initialize(distance, nodesCount);`

Comment: @Michi no, for passing a VLA, the size argument must appear **before** the VLA itself

Comment: @FelixPalmen You right, I was missing something here :D

Comment: but one more thing: I tried only to swap the argument, but the result is wrong. it only gets solved when I fix the (nodesCount+1) part. what is the magic here? I cannot see any differences between nodesCount and nodesCount+1 methods

Comment: Magic is `int (*distance)[nodesCount]` and `int (*distance)[nodesCount + 1]` declares `distance` a pointer to different data types.